# VB.NET Format row font in DataGridViewer

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn

I am binding a datagridview to a list of objects (report)

```
    DataGridView2.DataSource = Report
```

and because I am doing so, all rows' text format are identical.

Is there any way to format a particular row in the table ? For example, I would like to have row 1 's text in bold, the rest of rows are normal by default.

Many thanks

Comment: You state _“For example, I would like to have row 1 's text in bold, the rest of rows are normal”_... the visible row 1 in theory could be one of many rows. Example, the top visible row (Row 1?) has its font set to bold, then the user scrolls down enough such that the top rows scroll up out of the visible portion of the grid. Do you want only the first visible row to remain bold? I am not following exactly WHAT condition dictates, which row should be bold.

Answer (score 2):

Just as for a column, a row in a `DataGridView` has a `DefaultCellStyle`.  That `DataGridViewCellStyle` has a `Font` property, which you can set to a `Font` with the appropriate `Style` setting, e.g.

```
Dim cellStyle = myDataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle
Dim font = cellStyle.Font

cellStyle.Font = New Font(font, font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold)
```

EDIT: I have realised that that code will fail if you haven't already explicitly set the `Font` for that row.  If every cell is inheriting its style from the grid then you need to get the font from the grid too:

```
Dim font = myDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font

myDataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(font, font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold)
```

Comment: This solution would change the fonts of all cells in the table., not just one row.

Comment: Except it wouldn't.

Comment: @N.T.C ti will, but first you need get first row from datagriview: `myDataGridViewRow = yourDataGridView.Rows(0)` and because there is possibility that DataGridView doesn't have any rows, you need to check first is there any rows before accessing first row by index

Comment: @Fabio, I'm not sure whether you mistyped or not but it will NOT change the font of every cell in the grid.  It will only change the font of the cells in the row referred to by `myDataGridViewRow`. How you obtain that reference and what row that is is up to you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, OP's question was about how you can change format of particular row - _Is there any way to format a particular row in the table?_. Font was used only as a sample of property need to be changed in that rows. So by saying _How you obtain that reference and what row that is is up to you_ - you ignore main question and concentrate only on the font, which is not important for this question

Comment: How you access the row you want IS irrelevant to how you format a row. You do the formatting via the `DefaultCellStyle` for the row, as I have demonstrated. If you want change something other than the font then use a property other than `Font` but it would still be a property of that same `DefaultCellStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event and change style of every cell if row index is 0.

```
Private Sub YourDataGridView_CellFormatting(sender AS Object, 
                                            e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
    If e.RowIndex <> 0 Then Exit Sub

    ' Use e.CellStyle for formatting a cell
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Grey;
    e.CellStyle.Font = yourFontForFirstRow
End Sub
```

Notice that `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event occurs every time control is painting, so you need to be careful and do not execute "heavy" logic in that event. [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried your method, but it wasn't working , nothing was changed in the cell style.

Comment: @N.T.C - did you subscribe to the event by using `AddHandler yourDataGridView.CellFormatting, AddressOf YourDataGridView_CellFormatting` in constructor or by adding `Handles yourDataGridView.CellFormatting` to the method declaration?